# error: service 'lb-compiler' did not start. Aborting

Tags: logicblox

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. While installing logicblox, I got the following errors. How should I address it?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/opt/logicblox-4.1.4$ lb services start
2015-11-26 23:45:07-0800 - info: saving current logs in '/home/ubuntu/lb_deployment/logs/20151126_2345'
2015-11-26 23:45:07-0800 - info: starting service 'lb-compiler' ...
2015-11-26 23:45:08-0800 - info: waiting for service 'lb-compiler' to start (10 seconds remaining)
2015-11-26 23:45:09-0800 - info: waiting for service 'lb-compiler' to start (9 seconds remaining)
2015-11-26 23:45:11-0800 - info: waiting for service 'lb-compiler' to start (8 seconds remaining)
2015-11-26 23:45:12-0800 - info: waiting for service 'lb-compiler' to start (7 seconds remaining)
2015-11-26 23:45:13-0800 - info: waiting for service 'lb-compiler' to start (6 seconds remaining)
2015-11-26 23:45:15-0800 - info: waiting for service 'lb-compiler' to start (5 seconds remaining)
2015-11-26 23:45:16-0800 - info: waiting for service 'lb-compiler' to start (4 seconds remaining)
2015-11-26 23:45:17-0800 - info: waiting for service 'lb-compiler' to start (3 seconds remaining)
2015-11-26 23:45:19-0800 - info: waiting for service 'lb-compiler' to start (2 seconds remaining)
2015-11-26 23:45:20-0800 - info: waiting for service 'lb-compiler' to start (1 seconds remaining)
2015-11-26 23:45:21-0800 - error: service 'lb-compiler' did not start. Aborting.
```

Comment: First thing to do is to check the log file (in ~/lb_deployment/logs/current/lb_compiler.log`). You'll find more details about the reason of the error.

Comment: yes, that solve the problem, it is due to java installation problem, thanks!

Comment: @AmineHajyoussef you might consider moving your comment to an answer so OP can mark it as a solution. Right now this question still shows up as unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is to check the log file (in `~/lb_deployment/logs/current/lb_compiler.log`). You'll find more details about the reason of the error.